# Cannot change column to integer from character varying, but need to query the string >

Tags: php, postgresql

I cannot change the column to integer, which would solve this.

So I have a column full of strings which are numbers which I need to query and get numbers greater than the query

Really I just don't want it thinking nulls are duplicates because many are null (which is fine) and all the existing ones are 5 digit, so I thought I'd query for values over 100

```
AND id IS NOT NULL
```

doesn't work

```
AND id >100
```

nor does

```
and id > \'100\'
```

which gives me wrong results

Full query is

```
if (empty($alertLevel)) {
    $dupesId = -1;

    $sql = 'select max(person_id) ' .
             'from people ' . 
            'where person_id < ? ' .
              'and status not in (\'cancel\', \'fail\') ' .
              'and id = ? ' .
              'and id >100'; // this line hates me
    $v = array();
    $v[] = $tran['person_id'];
    $v[] = $tran['id'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($v);
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    if (!is_bool($r)) $dupesId = $r[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_number()`:

```
postgres=# create table foo (id text, name text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into foo values (generate_series(95,105),'foo');
INSERT 0 11
postgres=# select * from foo where id > 100;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text > integer
LINE 1: select * from foo where id > 100;
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres=# select * from foo where to_number(id,'99999') > 100;
 id  | name 
-----+------
 101 | foo
 102 | foo
 103 | foo
 104 | foo
 105 | foo
(5 rows)
```

The `99999` just [helps the function interpret the value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)

You **should** also be able to simply cast (not sure if you already tried it and run into some problem):

```
postgres=# select * from foo where id::int > 100;
 id  | name 
-----+------
 101 | foo
 102 | foo
 103 | foo
 104 | foo
 105 | foo
(5 rows)
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: how do you do that? I'm using phppgadmin I assume you mean changing the column?

Comment: can I use "and id::int > 100" without the quotes of course

Comment: Cool, had no idea I could cast mid query... great day to you